# Nodejs local API does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing an university project with NodeJs but I have some trouble in testing it in local.

This is the problem:
I have a GET API "/api/services/names" and the NodeJS server is running on port 8080.

If I test the API with Postmanor by putting the URL in the Chrome bar ("http://localhost:8080/api/services/names") it works fine and I can get my response.

The problem is that if I test it in my local website using `fetch()` inside this function:

```
function fetchServicesNames(){
    fetch('/api/services/names')
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            data.map(addServiceLink);
        });
}
```

The Javascript console gives me this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I noticed that when I hover the console error, it shows the request string "http://localhost/api/services/names" without the port. But I don't think this is the problem because when I deploy the application on the Heroku platform it works fine... the problem is just in localhost (I'm working with a mid 2010 macbook pro with Mac OSX 10.10.2).

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Edit:
as requested I'm adding here the server code

```
// server.js for Hypermedia Application project.

// BASE SETUP
//============================================================

// call packages
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// we use body-parser, so we need to be able to read data either from 
// GET and POST:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// setting the application port to listen 
var serverPort = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// --- database connection omitted ---

// API ROUTES
// ================================================================
// first of all: get the Router
var router = express.Router();

/**
 * Services names
 * /api/services/names  - get   - get all services ids and names
 */
router.route('/services/names')
.get(function (req, res) {

    Service.find({}, 'id name', function (err, services) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(services);
    });  

});

// --- Other APIs omitted ---

// REGISTER ROUTES:
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);


// START THE SERVER
//===================================================================
app.set("port", serverPort);

app.listen(serverPort, function() {
    console.log(`Your app is ready at port ${serverPort}`);
});
```

Comment: Show us the server code.

Comment: It's a normal browser workflow, if u are fetching `/api` browser will fetch opened url + `/api/`, just fetch full address, like `fetch('localhost:8080/api...')`, so or so in production, if everything written good you will have some type of constant with API url, and will fetch it using this constant.

Comment: it gives to me
    `script.js:47 Fetch API cannot load localhost:5000/api/services/names. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

Port is changed because of my team choose

Comment: approve my answer

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: ok sorry sir =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at your server page you add

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

before your API's

it might help you for CORS

Answer (score -1):

Dear i suggest you to write total Path like

```
http://localhost:<your port number>/api/services/names
```

inside fetch()and u check once

I too tried and i got Success

Comment: I tried and it gives to me this error: `Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/services/names. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I don't know what it can be

Comment: @DavideCremona that error message is pretty descriptive. you're making a cross-origin request, and the server isn't allowing cross-origin requests by omitting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I know but if I write in the web browser `localhost:5000/api/services/names` without the `http://` part it works.
I don't understand why it does not work if I remove the port (in the deployed app it works)

Comment: Because if you remove the port, you're hitting a different origin. thus making it a cross-origin request.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty a newbuy with REST and NodeJS... What can I do to make it work locally?

Comment: make the server support cors, or make the server same origin.

Comment: at your server page you keep `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});`   it might help you for CORS

Comment: you can approve my answer if u like

Answer (score -1):

Hi try modifying the line like `fetch('http://'+window.location.host+':8080/api/services/...)`

Comment: `window.location.host` will echo current server host only. Like `localhost`.So let's concatenate port also.Like 
`fetch('http://'+window.location.host+':8080/api/services/...)`. It will do the trick